# A simple temperature sensing switch circuit to power a heater to prevent frost damage

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, thermistor

Ok, up front, I am a huge noob at electronics design, not an engineer, just a dangerous man with a bunch of electrical components and a moderately good soldering iron, and just enough knowledge to think this task would be simple. Uh-huh.

I want to use a USB powered coffee cup heater to prevent a small jar of liquid from freezing when the icy winds of winter blow, :-). I intend to use a DC 5v wall wart for power but wish for the heater to switch on at 0 degrees C, and remain on until ambient temperatures rise to 3 to 5 degrees C.
I have been browsing on the Net for a while now, but am confused by some of the circuitry I have found, and been unsuccessful at breadboarding a functioning model. I understand the concept of using a thermistor and a trim-pot to bias a transistor (Probably a Darlington pair?) but the devil lies in the details, right.
Am I naive to think that I can accomplish this without a PLC? If that is the way to go, I am way over my head and will need professional help... In several disciplines LOL

---

Thank you all for taking the time to help. In the wee hours of the morning, I may have come up with a solution.. I realized that I may have been trying to solve the wrong problem, in that I actually don't need a switching circuit at all but rather, a current control circuit that increases/decreases current flowing through the heater inversely to sensed temperature increase/decrease. The unit is single source (wall wart) so if I choose the right thermistor value and trim-pot combination as a tunable voltage divider circuit which in turn will be applied to the base of an appropriate darlington pair transistor, wouldn't that control the current through the heater on a sliding scale? The colder it gets, the more current is applied, and when it warms up, the current is reduced?

Comment: You could probably find a bimetallic fixed temperature switch and just put it in series with your supply.

Comment: You can buy heat tape intended to keep pipes from freezing, and just wrap it around the jar. Thermostat is built in.

Comment: Search "heat tracing" cables.

Comment: Here you go:    https://www.ebay.com/itm/372633269101?hash=item56c2ac736d:g:VpYAAOSwyD9bb2WI&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoARGgSrJr7HsRUvHpwJlfzmFG1t6pObWVCmCnrO1TJqtQQgT1hdaieX7yxPvX7YltSMjkC3wcFh22uRY8zHEnUSnUDPM%2FUyW4sFLCyzJE%2Fi0hsNjhEXQxU%2Blqm6KY45USaie0d3zOnd2An6TQOsVZruwR2bZYMs1%2F0jmXQTtBHPpmfKRkVYc%2FMCyWeifnNFqW0ZDnjhNUMklr7RhV%2BS46PE%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR8i1reiPYQ

Comment: At least show us the circuits you have tried and rejected, so we don't propose them again.

Comment: @John D, Thanks... I have done a lot of looking and had discussions with the guys at Mouser, but was only able to find high current, high power, high priced industrial grade items :-(..

Comment: @MarkLeavitt Thanks. These items are far too bulky and powerful for my project. Jar is only 1.5" in diameter. I investigated this option at length, trying to find a source of the thermostats they use without success

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks. See my reply to Mark Leavitt

Comment: @KyleB, Thanks, sadly that item does not ship to Canada... I will look for it and ask the guys at Mouser..

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thanks. https://www.circuits-diy.com/cold-sensor-switch-using-ntc-thermistor/

Comment: @BobBaker - Hi, You posted an "answer" but it still asked for help. As you are the OP, you would only write an answer if you fully solved the problem yourself & the topic can be closed *with no more help needed*. If you ask for more advice in an "answer" then it becomes a *question* again! For the Stack Exchange "model" to work, people must not ask for help in an answer - it is supposed to be a clear *solution*. Therefore I have moved your post to become an update in the question. If you make a new final solution, on your own & unrelated to another answer, you can post it as a self-answer.

Comment: (continued) Please read the [tour] & [help] as a minimum, to see how Stack Exchange differs from typical forums. (There is also a long [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)).

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for correcting my error. I could not figure out how to add to/modify my question using edit. I tried to do it through a comment, but there were too many characters, and that's how/why I opted to answer my own question. I am also not clear about how to draw/post a circuit diagram. I am trying to learn so please bear with me. So, yes, I still need help with the circuit design, component choices and values etc.

Comment: @BobBaker - Hi (a) On Stack Exchange (SE) don't add important new details relevant to everyone in a comment. Instead [edit] the question to add them (follow that [edit] link or click the "Edit" button below your question. Only write a *comment* when it is a short-lived, disposable response to one or a few people. (I say "disposable" because on SE, *comments* should be thought of as temporary notes; only Q & A have visible edit histories and longevity.) To add a schematic, either use Ctrl+G in the edit box to upload an image, or Ctrl+M in the edit box to use the schematic editor.

Comment: (continued) I am concerned about the "change in direction" in your question. I suspect this is becoming an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) where you are asking for help based on what you think the solution should be, instead of asking about (and allowing answers to) the actual problem, without specifying the solution (e.g. Darlington transistor) yourself. Please try to avoid that trap. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I'd have moved this to chat, but do not have enough reputation,,, so maybe this question should be deleted and I could try again from a new understanding of how this site works, and try to avoid my mistakes and the XY problem? will do if you thinks thats the way to proceed here

Comment: @BobBaker - "*maybe this question should be deleted*" That is no longer allowed, as a site member has spent time writing an answer to the question given and we're not going to delete their answer (which would happen if the question was deleted). Please try to work now within the limits you have set. Please consider the answer given. If you don't understand it or need clarification, ask in a *comment* below that answer. You should not modify the question in a way that would invalidate that answer. Hopefully that answer will solve your given question, even if it wasn't what you expected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a circuit that should work for you. M1 needs to be a logic-level MOSFET rated for Rds(on) at 5V. Eg. IRLZ44 but there are better ones, especially in SMT.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcPxeg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The values of R4 and R7 are chosen for a thermistor part number [NDBG104J3950B1F](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/electronic-components/resources/data-sheet/eaton-ndbg-glass-sealed-axial-lead-ntc-thermistor--data-sheet-elx1107-en.pdf), which is cheap and conveniently has a table of values in the datasheet. If you pick another or want to adjust the switching points, just pick  R7 and R4 to determine the on/off thresholds.

It turns on when Rth || R7 = R4 and off when Rth = R4|| R7 .

In this case it should switch on when the thermistor is at about 27.77k (0°C) and off at 23.33k (4°C).